# Visual studio cannot open source file <vulkan.h>

Tags: c++, vulkan

I've looked it up and the internet says to simply add the directory. But I have already done that (I believe).

[This is the folder:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTjgM.png)
it is C:\VulkanSDK\1.1.126.0\Include\vulkan  (maybe i'm wrong?)

[this is the place where I included the folder:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPhBs.png)

This is the line of code:     #include 
the error says "cannot open source file"vulkan.h"

I have also tried including just the "Include" folder and then typing in code "include" but that dint work either.

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Just to confirm, try it under C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories. That is what I typically use.

Comment: You seem to have `"` preceding the path. Remove and see if it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, you want include path to be `C:\VulkanSDK\1.1.126.0\Include` directory, not `C:\VulkanSDK\1.1.126.0\Include\vulkan` directory.  The correct include declaration is:

```
#include <vulkan/vulkan.h>
```

Second, I would suggest adding the include to the *Additional Include Directories*, as seen here:

[image]

Comment: AHA, thank you, it was the Additional Include directories that did the trick. thank you!

Comment: It would be better to write it as "%VULKAN_SDK%\Include" because then you don't have to update the path when you upgrade the SDK to a new version.